# airflow.exceptions.TaskNotFound: Task processing_user not found

Tags: python, airflow

Hi I installed airflow in VirtualBox, while testing the below Code using the command `airflow tasks test user_processing processing_user  2020-01-02` I am getting warning message and TaskNotFound error. (Followed Marc Lamberti course). Thanks in Advance.

My Code: created table using sqlite operator, used http operator to download the user from the API then used Python operator to process the information

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from datetime import datetime
from airflow.providers.sqlite.operators.sqlite import SqliteOperator
from airflow.providers.http.sensors.http import HttpSensor
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
import json


from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from pandas import json_normalize
default_args = {'start_date' : datetime(2021,10,11)}

def _processing_user(ti):
    users = ti.xcom_pull(task_id=['extracting_user'])
    if not len(users) or 'results' not in users[0]:
        raise ValueError('User is Empty')
    user = users[0]['results'][0]
    processed_user = json_normalize({
        'firstname':user['name']['first'],
        'lastname':user['name']['last'],
        'country':user['location']['country'],
        'username':user['login']['username'],
        'password':user['login']['password'],
        'email': user['email']
    })
    processed_user.to_csv('/tmp/processed_user.csv', index=None, header=False)


with DAG('user_processing',schedule_interval='@daily',default_args=default_args,catchup=False) as dag:
        creating_table = SqliteOperator(
            task_id='creating_table',
            sqlite_conn_id='db_sqlite',
            sql='''
                CREATE TABLE users (
                firstname TEXT NOT NULL,
                lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
                country TEXT NOT NULL,
                password TEXT NOT NULL,
                email TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
               );
               '''
    )

        is_api_available = HttpSensor(
           task_id='is_api_available',
           http_conn_id='user_api',
           endpoint='api/')

        extracting_user = SimpleHttpOperator(
            task_id='extracting_user',
            http_conn_id='user_api',
            endpoint='api/',
            method='GET',
            response_filter=lambda response: json.loads(response.text),
            log_response=True
        )
    
        processing_user = PythonOperator(
           task_id='Processing_user',
           python_callable= _processing_user
        )
```

Warning Message:

```
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,227] {dagbag.py:487} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/airflow/airflow/dags
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,577] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_1>, task_group_function.task_2 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,579] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency 
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,586] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_1>, task_group_function.task_2 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,588] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency 
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,594] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency 
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,602] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_3>, task_group_function.task_2 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,604] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_2>, task_group_function.task_3 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,607] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_3>, task_group_function.task_2 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,609] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_2>, task_group_function.task_3 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,612] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency <Task(_PythonDecoratedOperator): task_group_function.task_3>, task_group_function.task_2 already registered for DAG: example_task_group_decorator
[2021-10-14 19:02:47,615] {baseoperator.py:1287} WARNING - Dependency
```

Error Message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/airflow/sandbox/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
        args.func(args)
      File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 91, in wrapper
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 381, in task_test
        task = dag.get_task(task_id=args.task_id)
      File "/home/airflow/sandbox/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1546, in get_task
        raise TaskNotFound(f"Task {task_id} not found")
    airflow.exceptions.TaskNotFound: Task processing_user not found
```

Answer (score 0):

For the exception, it looks like the `task_id` you are trying to reference is actually "Processing_user" (as written in the DAG) rather than "processing_user" (as written in the CLI command); only a small capitalization difference. Task ID is case-sensitive.

Try making the `task_id` value in the CLI command the same as what's written in the DAG (or vice versa).